# Can this script be streamlined?

Tags: powershell, csv, logging, active-directory

I've moved this to the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178623/) forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Didn't know that forum existed; I'll gladly move it if that's what's needed.  However, there's still an issue with the logging....

Comment: For help with code that is not working the way you expected please reduce your code to a [mcve] and describe the actual and desired results in more detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belong on Code Review.